# CPU soft lockup on Ubuntu and pthreads

Tags: multithreading, ubuntu, pthreads

I have a daemon with multiple pthreads (about 4). One of threads provides high precision timer with microsecond resolution using POSIX `gettimeofday`. Using `gettimeofday` results in very high CPU usage and this is expected behaviour, so thread moved to separate core of processor via  `pthread_attr_setaffinity_np`. All is ok, but Ubuntu 14.04 sometimes fails with error in `syslog`:

```
whoopsie[1467]: Not online; processing later (/var/crash/linux-image-3.13.0-34-
generic.144394.crash).

Soft lockup CPU#1 stuck for 22s
```

What does it mean?

Comment: any update on the problem?

Comment: i just make of pthread_yield() on thread and problem now is gone.

Answer (score 1):

`whoopsie` is the "Ubuntu Error Reporting" daemon.
And the `Soft lockup CPU#1 stuck for` message does not appear to be directly connected to what you are doing with the thread and `gettimeofday`. It might be a system stability problem under heavy load as [discussed here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2205211) or [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=990806).